# Finding out whether two discrete variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution of not

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have a PMF for $(X,Y)$ given by this tabel

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l|cccc} 
& Y=1 & Y=2 & Y=3 & Y=4 \\
\hline X=1 & 0.04 & 0.07 & 0.10 & 0.01 \\
X=2 & 0.17 & 0.13 & 0.05 & 0.03 \\
X=3 & 0.06 & 0.10 & 0.08 & 0.02 \\
X=4 & 0.05 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.01
\end{array}
\end{equation}

I'm ask two find out whether $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution or not.
But what does this mean? Does it mean that $P(X=x)=P(Y=y), \: \forall x,y, \: x=y$? I'm actually not sure how to formulate mathematically (notation). Use use the Blitzstein Hwang textbook, but I could not find a definition in this book.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are both random variables that only take values in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ then they have the same distribution if $$P(X=k)=P(Y=k)\text{ for every }k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$$

So to be found and compared are values $P(X=k)$ (summation of row $k$) and $P(Y=k)$ (summation of column $k$).

Comment: What if the support was different?

Comment: If some $s$ exists with $P(X=s)>0$ and $P(Y=s)=0$ (so different supports) then you can conclude at once that $X$ and $Y$ do not have the same distribution.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks. Good explanation.

Comment: Just to be sure: if $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution it means that the have identical PMFs? So $p_X (k) = p_Y (k), \: \forall k$

Comment: Yes, that is correct for discrete random variables. Not every random variable has a PMF though. More generally: they have equal distribution if they have equal CDF.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution if $P(X=x)=P(Y=x)$ for all $x$.